# Print screen with SVG element using shinyscreenshot only

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I have this code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyscreenshot)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("text", "Enter some text", "test"),
  actionButton("go", "Take a screenshot"),
  flexdashboard::gauge(value = 50, min = 1, max = 100)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    screenshot()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I need to print the screen and make the `SVG` elements appear. I tried using this JS:

```
    "<script>
        /// capture shiny screenshot SVG
$(function() {

      function take(targetElem) {
        // First render all SVGs to canvases
        var elements = targetElem.find('svg').map(function() {
            var svg = $(this);
            var canvas = $('<canvas></canvas>');
            svg.replaceWith(canvas);

            // Get the raw SVG string and curate it
            var content = svg.wrap('<p></p>').parent().html();
            content = content.replace(/xlink:title='hide\\/show'/g, '');
            content = encodeURIComponent(content);
            svg.unwrap();

            // Create an image from the svg
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + content;
            image.onload = function() {
                canvas[0].width = image.width;
                canvas[0].height = image.height;

                // Render the image to the canvas
                var context = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
                context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
            };
            return {
                svg: svg,
                canvas: canvas
            };
        });
        targetElem.imagesLoaded(function() {
            // At this point the container has no SVG, it only has HTML and Canvases.
            html2canvas(targetElem[0], {
                onrendered: function(canvas) {
                    // Put the SVGs back in place
                    elements.each(function() {
                        this.canvas.replaceWith(this.svg);
                    });

                    // Do something with the canvas, for example put it at the bottom
                 $(canvas).appendTo('body');
                }
            })
        })
    }

})
        </script>"
```

But it does not work. I only need to use `shinyscreenshot`. I am aware of these issues:

[one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70379277/9610309)

[two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70379277/9610309)

I need to use only `shinyscreenshot` for my app. How can I tweak the `JS` to make capturing work for `SVG` elements?

Comment: Do you mean the SVG does not appear on the screenshot? That's strange, this works for **plotly** graphics, which are in SVG.

Comment: The graph with plotly appears, but its legend does not appear (maybe because I am using ggplotly). Neither do the gauges with flexdashboard appear (as I provided in the example).

Comment: `capture` is working fine for me. Is there a reason why you can use js and not this package?

Answer (score 0):

since by reading the comment `capture` is off the table i'm trying to include a Javascrpit function in the Shiny server function converting the SVG before the screenshot.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    shinyjs::runjs("
      function take(targetElem) {
        // First render all SVGs to canvases
        var elements = targetElem.find('svg').map(function() {
            var svg = $(this);
            var canvas = $('<canvas></canvas>');
            svg.replaceWith(canvas);

            // Get the raw SVG string and curate it
            var content = svg.wrap('<p></p>').parent().html();
            content = content.replace(/xlink:title='hide\\/show'/g, '');
            content = encodeURIComponent(content);
            svg.unwrap();

            // Create an image from the svg
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + content;
            image.onload = function() {
                canvas[0].width = image.width;
                canvas[0].height = image.height;

                // Render the image to the canvas
                var context = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
                context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
            };
            return {
                svg: svg,
                canvas: canvas
            };
        });
      }
    ")
    screenshot()
  })
}
```

i think this is a good starting point to think how to integrate shiny with Javascript.
You would still need to know hot to handle the svgs informations, where and how to hangle the specifi SVG elements that you want to convert.